# My code has this error: Error using trainNetwork Number of observations in X and Y disagree

Tags: matlab, resnet

My code has this error: Error using trainNetwork Number of observations in X and Y disagree.

I checked the sizes using this code:
disp(['Size of featuresArray: ' num2str(size(featuresArray))]);
disp(['Size of trainingLabels: ' num2str(size(trainingLabels))]);

and these were generated:
Size of featuresArray: 957  100
Size of trainingLabels: 957    1

```
% Import required libraries
import matlab.io.datastore.ImageDatastore
import matlab.io.datastore.*
import matlab.io.datastore.augmenters.image.*
import matlab.io.datastore.augmenters.*
import matlab.io.datastore.TransformedDatastore.*

% Set the folder containing the image dataset
datasetFolder = 'C:\Users\xinai\Downloads\Images';

% Create an imageDatastore for the dataset
imds = imageDatastore(datasetFolder, 'IncludeSubfolders', true, 'LabelSource', 'foldernames');

% Split the dataset into training and validation sets
[trainingData, validationData] = splitEachLabel(imds, 0.7, 'randomized');

% Define the rotation range for augmentation
rotationRange = [-10 10];

% Define the input size
inputSize = [224 224 3];

% Define the number of GLCM features
numGLCMFeatures = 5;

% Define the number of HSV histogram bins
numHSVHistBins = 32;

% Define the number of PCA components
numComponents = 100;

% Define the preprocessing function
preprocessFcn = @(img) {im2gray(img), hsvHistogram(img, numHSVHistBins)};

% Initialize feature matrices
numObservations = numel(trainingData.Files);
glcmFeatures = zeros(numObservations, numGLCMFeatures);
hsvHistograms = zeros(numObservations, numHSVHistBins * 3);

% Extract GLCM features and HSV histograms
reset(trainingData);
for i = 1:numObservations
    % Read the image
    img = read(trainingData);

    % Apply data augmentation
    imgAugmented = augmentedImageDatastore(inputSize, img, ...
        'DataAugmentation', imageDataAugmenter('RandRotation', rotationRange, ...
        'RandXReflection', true, 'RandYReflection', true, ...
        'RandXScale', [0.8 1.2], 'RandYScale', [0.8 1.2]));

     % Read the image
    img = readimage(trainingData, i);

    % Apply data augmentation
    augmentedData = augment(augmenter, img);

    % Convert the image to grayscale
    grayImg = rgb2gray(img);

    % Calculate GLCM features
    glcm = graycomatrix(grayImg);
    stats = graycoprops(glcm);
    glcmFeatures(i, :) = [stats.Contrast, stats.Correlation, stats.Energy, stats.Homogeneity, stats.Homogeneity];

    % Calculate HSV histogram
    hsvImg = rgb2hsv(img);
    hHist = imhist(hsvImg(:, :, 1), numHSVHistBins);
    sHist = imhist(hsvImg(:, :, 2), numHSVHistBins);
    vHist = imhist(hsvImg(:, :, 3), numHSVHistBins);
    hsvHistograms(i, :) = [hHist', sHist', vHist'];
end

% Concatenate GLCM features and HSV histograms
features = [glcmFeatures, hsvHistograms];

% Perform PCA on the features
[coeff, score, ~, ~, explained] = pca(features);
selectedComponents = coeff(:, 1:numComponents);
projectedFeatures = score(:, 1:numComponents);

% Create a new table with the projected features and labels
pcaTrainingData = table(projectedFeatures, trainingData.Labels, 'VariableNames', {'Features', 'Labels'});

% Select a subset of training labels to match the number of observations in projectedFeatures
numObservations = size(pcaTrainingData, 1);
pcaTrainingData = pcaTrainingData(1:numObservations, :);

% Convert the training labels to categorical
trainingLabels = categorical(pcaTrainingData.Labels);

% Convert the features table to an array
featuresArrayTranspose = projectedFeatures;

% Check the sizes of featuresArrayTranspose and trainingLabels
size(featuresArrayTranspose)
size(trainingLabels)


% Load the ResNet-50 network
net = resnet50;

% Replace the fully connected layer with a new layer
numClasses = numel(categories(trainingLabels));
newFullyConnectedLayer = fullyConnectedLayer(numClasses, 'Name', 'fc', 'WeightLearnRateFactor', 10, 'BiasLearnRateFactor', 10);

% Remove the last layers
lgraph = layerGraph(net);
lgraph = removeLayers(lgraph, {'fc1000', 'fc1000_softmax', 'ClassificationLayer_fc1000'});

% Connect the new fully connected layer to the network
newFullyConnectedLayer = fullyConnectedLayer(numClasses, 'Name', 'fc', 'WeightLearnRateFactor', 10, 'BiasLearnRateFactor', 10);
lgraph = addLayers(lgraph, newFullyConnectedLayer);
lgraph = connectLayers(lgraph, 'avg_pool', 'fc');

% Set the output layer
newSoftmaxLayer = softmaxLayer('Name', 'softmax');
newClassificationLayer = classificationLayer('Name', 'ClassificationLayer');
lgraph = addLayers(lgraph, newSoftmaxLayer);
lgraph = addLayers(lgraph, newClassificationLayer);
lgraph = connectLayers(lgraph, 'fc', 'softmax');
lgraph = connectLayers(lgraph, 'softmax', 'ClassificationLayer');

% Set training options
miniBatchSize = 10;
numIterationsPerEpoch = floor(numel(trainingData.Files) / miniBatchSize);
trainOpts = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'MiniBatchSize', miniBatchSize, ...
    'MaxEpochs', 50, ...
    'InitialLearnRate', 1e-3, ...
    'Shuffle', 'every-epoch', ...
    'ValidationData', validationData, ...
    'ValidationFrequency', numIterationsPerEpoch, ...
    'Verbose', false, ...
    'Plots', 'training-progress');

% Select a subset of featuresArray to match the number of observations in trainingLabels
featuresArraySubset = featuresArrayTranspose(1:numObservations, :);

% Transpose the features array to match the network's input requirements
featuresArrayTranspose = featuresArraySubset';

% Check the sizes of featuresArrayTranspose and trainingLabels
size(featuresArrayTranspose)
size(trainingLabels)

% Convert the training labels to categorical
trainingLabels = categorical(trainingLabels);

% Train the network
net = trainNetwork(featuresArrayTranspose, trainingLabels, lgraph, trainOpts);
```

Please help, I am desperate :(

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message, including the stack trace. Knowing where in the code the error happens makes it easier to find the problem.

Comment: the error occurs on this line:
% Train the network
net = trainNetwork(featuresArrayTranspose, trainingLabels, lgraph, trainOpts);